# ¿Por qué se desborda la gráfica?

Tags: javascript, html, css, chart.js

Estoy haciendo una gráfica usando Chart.js, la cuestión es que se desborda por debajo, traslapándose con el div inferior; es decir, la gráfica que está en el div con clase línea, se desborda con el div de la clase cuadro. ¿Cuál sería el problema que causa el traslape? Coloco el código a continuación:

```js
Chart.register(ChartDataLabels);

                var options = {
                  type: 'line',
                  data: {
                    labels: ['2003', '2004', '2005', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015', '2016','2017', '2018', '2019', '2020'],
                    datasets: [{
                      fill:false,
                      label: 'Cantidad Estudiantes',
                      data: [12,15, 9, 0, 9,13,13,16,26,22, 0,18, 9,10,11, 8, 9,12],
                      backgroundColor: 'red',
                      
                      borderColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                        
                      ],
                      borderWidth: 3
                    }]
                  },
                  options: {
                    responsive:true,    
                    plugins: {
                      legend: {
                        display:false, 
                        title:{text:"Número de Estudiantes por país (2003-2020)", display:true}},
                      datalabels: {
                        backgroundColor: function(context) {
                          return context.dataset.backgroundColor;
                        },
                        borderColor: 'orange',
                        borderRadius: 25,
                        borderWidth: 2,
                        color: 'black',
                        font: {
                          weight: 'bold'
                        },
                        padding: 4,
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }

                var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainerC').getContext('2d');
                new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```css
.grafica{
  height:68vh;
}
.texto{
  background-color: black;
  color:white;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
  width:27vh;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center  ;
  margin: 2px auto;

}
.linea {
  height:60vh;
}


.cuadro {
  background-color:black;
  color:white;
  height:32vh;
  
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="grafica">
    <div class="texto">
      Número de Estudiantes por País (2003-2020)
    </div>
    <div class="linea">
      <canvas id="chartJSContainerC"></canvas>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="cuadro">
    <p>Para que el programa siga adelante en esta tarea, es necesario que como iglesia nos involucremos a favor de los pueblos que no cuentan con la palabra de Dios en el idioma que mejor entienden. Este involucramiento va desde la intercesión, acompañamiento,
      capacitación, y sostenimiento financiero, hasta la obediencia en el envío</p>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.3.2/chart.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2.0.0-rc"></script>
  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+YQ4JLhjyBLPDQt//I+STsc9iw4uQqACwlvpslubQzn4u2UU2UFM80nGisd026JF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Bien por poner un ejemplo mínimo y verificable, dicho esto, veo bien el gráfico.

Comment: no se te coloca encima del div con el texto (class="cuadro")?

Comment: Osea el cuadro con el texto quieres que quede siempre debajo del gráfico?

Comment: Si, así mismo es la idea.

Comment: Yo creo que el problema son las alturas, puedes quitarlas y ver como funciona.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En mi opinión hay que reajustar las alturas. Aquí el ejemplo sacando las alturas:

```js
Chart.register(ChartDataLabels);

                var options = {
                  type: 'line',
                  data: {
                    labels: ['2003', '2004', '2005', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015', '2016','2017', '2018', '2019', '2020'],
                    datasets: [{
                      fill:false,
                      label: 'Cantidad Estudiantes',
                      data: [12,15, 9, 0, 9,13,13,16,26,22, 0,18, 9,10,11, 8, 9,12],
                      backgroundColor: 'red',
                      
                      borderColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                        
                      ],
                      borderWidth: 3
                    }]
                  },
                  options: {
                    responsive:true,    
                    plugins: {
                      legend: {
                        display:false, 
                        title:{text:"Número de Estudiantes por país (2003-2020)", display:true}},
                      datalabels: {
                        backgroundColor: function(context) {
                          return context.dataset.backgroundColor;
                        },
                        borderColor: 'orange',
                        borderRadius: 25,
                        borderWidth: 2,
                        color: 'black',
                        font: {
                          weight: 'bold'
                        },
                        padding: 4,
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }

                var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainerC').getContext('2d');
                new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```css
.grafica{
  /*height:67vh;*/
}
.texto{
  background-color: black;
  color:white;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
  width:27vh;
  /*height: 60px;*/
  text-align: center  ;
  margin: 2px auto;

}
.linea {
  /*height:60vh;*/
}


.cuadro {
  background-color:black;
  color:white;
  /*height:32vh;*/
  
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="grafica">
    <div class="texto">
      Número de Estudiantes por País (2003-2020)
    </div>
    <div class="linea">
      <canvas id="chartJSContainerC"></canvas>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="cuadro">
    <p>Para que el programa siga adelante en esta tarea, es necesario que como iglesia nos involucremos a favor de los pueblos que no cuentan con la palabra de Dios en el idioma que mejor entienden. Este involucramiento va desde la intercesión, acompañamiento,
      capacitación, y sostenimiento financiero, hasta la obediencia en el envío</p>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.3.2/chart.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2.0.0-rc"></script>
  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+YQ4JLhjyBLPDQt//I+STsc9iw4uQqACwlvpslubQzn4u2UU2UFM80nGisd026JF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  

</body>

</html>
```

Actualización:

El problema está originado por la altura del canvas, luego de cargar el html se carga el gráfico y a este,  chart.js le asigna una altura que resulta en un desborde el contenedor, se arregla si se le pone al canvas como máximo la altura del padre: `#chartJSContainerC{ max-height:60dv; }`. También se puede poner la opción `responsive:false` en los options de chart.js y definir las medidas manualmente.

Comment: Cuando alguien provea de una explicación mas precisa elimino la respuesta.

Comment: Tu opinión y respuesta son muy buenas y, si alguien tiene una explicación, puede agregarla o comentar para que tú lo hagas. +1

Comment: Muchas gracias @Emmeus, me sirvió mucho tu respuesta. Con tus modificaciones no se desborda.

Comment: Ahora si encontré y agregué la explicación de porque sucede lo que sucede.